# Scroll list selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I write a small script and got a trouble. I try to scroll down the list but it doesn't work properly. Here is my code

```
    def get_followers(self):
            try:
                self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a._t98z6')[0].click()
            except Exception as e:
                print("Sorry, i don't have access to your followers: {0}".format(e))
            else:
                followers = []
                while True:
                self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
                try:
                    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_css_selector('li._6e4x5')) #It doesn't find element.
                except:
                    break
            followers = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a._2g7d5.notranslate._o5iw8")
return followers
```

I also tried to use xpath like this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class = '_6e4x5']"))
```

[Screen of the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVC4o.png)
[Screen of the html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQV4x.png)

I really need your help. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please give the error and the screenshot of the list we need to know how  the list looks like and also give the html code of the element:  a._t98z6 and li._6e4x5  .  the class (_t98z6 and _6e4x5) looks like dynamical value,  are your sure they are not change when enter the page every time?

Comment: The class _t98z6 is not dynamical value, i'm sure.

Comment: Did you forgot upload the screenshot?

Comment: I edited my post. I added screenshots

Answer (score 0):

the follower list displayed in a pop-up and the pop-up has own scroll bar.
your code:

```
self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
```

can't control the scroll bar of the pop-up, but control the scroll bar of the whole page.

So delete that code,  Additional if you only want to get all followers' name, you no need to scroll down to the bottom of pop-up, but if you want to click on any follower which is not visible in pop-up, you need to scroll down the bar of the pop-up.

```
def get_followers(self):
      followers = []
      try:
          self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a._t98z6')[0].click()
          // I guess above click will make the follower list pop-up display out
          except Exception as e:
              print("Sorry, i don't have access to your followers: {0}".format(e))
          else:
             followers = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("li._6e4x5 a.notranslate")
       return followers
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. My goal is to get all followers' name. I can't write like this:  followers = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("li._6e4x5 a.notranslate") because it displays only 10 followers. So, to get all of them i must to scroll down the page

Comment: Only 10 followers are visible not mean the pop-up not load all followers when the pop-up come out.  you can open your page in chrome and open devtool, then in element tab try li._6e4x5, if find more than 10 elements, my guess is correct, so you no need to scroll down.   I'm not sure how did the web developer implement the follower list,  if developer make the code to load followers dynamically when user moving the scroll bar,  in this case you need to scroll down.  But i guess developer not implement as that.